# How to migrate large amount of data from MySQL database to SQL Server database with C# service

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012

I have a MySQL database contains large amount of data.

I wanted to write a C# service program to migrate that data into SQL Server database.(Service should work fine with Insert as well as update with out  performance issue).

Please help us if there is a way to accomplish this. If there  is another way to achieve this is also fine. But, the MySQL client is not present in the local machine. But we could access the database from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import and export functions in sqlserver, after installing a odbc mysql